# How do I translate this command line curl into php curl?

Tags: php, curl, command-line, command

I've got a command line curl bit of code that I want to translate into php.  I'm struggling.

Here's the line of code

```
$ curl -H "Authorization: 622cee5f8c99c81e87614e9efc63eddb" https://api.service.com/member
```

the big string would be a variable I'd pass into it.

What does this look like in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to analyze what that line does:

```
$ curl -H "Authorization: 622cee5f8c99c81e87614e9efc63eddb" https://api.service.com/member
```

It's not complex, you find all switches explained on [curl's manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> [`-H, --header <header>`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-H): (HTTP) Extra header to use when getting a web page. You may specify any number of extra headers. [...]

You can add a header via [`curl_setopt_array`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/curl_setopt_array) in PHP (all available options are explained at [`curl_setopt`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/curl_setopt)):

```
$ch = curl_init('https://api.service.com/member');
// set URL and other appropriate options
$options = array(        
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Authorization: 622cee5f8c99c81e87614e9efc63eddb"),
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
curl_exec($ch); // grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_close($ch);
```

In case curl is blocked, you can do that as well with PHP's HTTP capabilities which works even if curl is not available (and it takes curl if curl is available internally):

```
$options = array('http' => array(
    'header' => array("Authorization: 622cee5f8c99c81e87614e9efc63eddb"),
));
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents('https://api.service.com/member', 0, $context);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the `curl_*` functions in php. 
With `curl_setopt()` you can set the headers of the request.

Answer (score 1):

1) you can use [Curl functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

2) you can use [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

```
exec('curl -H "Authorization: 622cee5f8c99c81e87614e9efc63eddb" https://api.service.com/member');
```

3) you can use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) if you only want the information as string...

```
<?php
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Authorization: 622cee5f8c99c81e87614e9efc63eddb"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('https://api.service.com/member', false, $context);
?>
```